# Prizes and awards: what about travel grants?

Tags: funding, postdocs, travel, awards

I am applying for various postdoc grants at the moment. They all have some section concerning Prizes and Awards. While I understand that this obviously includes things like 'best poster presentation' or 'best dissertation', I wonder whether competitive travel grants fall under this category? Often they involve the writing of a research proposal, have a low success rate and can entail large sums of money so I am sure this is relevant for applications.

If not under this section, where should I mention these things? I have never seen a field specifically dedicated to travel grants and I do not think they can be mentioned under something like research grants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, travel grants belong there, in particular if there is no other field like "personal scholarships/stipendia" or similar.

Also, you are probably overthinking this, as even if you find another more or less appropriate section and put your travel grant in both of them, it won't hurt you application chances in any way.

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose are you listing this? Is it your CV for your website, a job application, or something else?

If this is a casual CV posting, then you can do whatever you like, and I've seen all sorts of things to make oneself unique. Funding agencies, at the other extreme, generally speaking, have pretty rigid formatting instructions (and often different names!) for CVs (aka biosketches), and you should follow those to the letter. They may or may not let you include such a grant. A job application is up to the place you're applying and will may let you apply with any CV format you like. My recommendation would be to look at any posted CVs of their current staff in the position you're applying for and shoot for a format that's pretty close to theirs. We allow the upload of two generic documents to our applications, a CV and a Letter of Interest, in any format you choose. It's up to the application reviewers to be impressed with the content they find, or not.

Comment: The first sentence of OP suggests they are applying for postdoctoral grants ("I am applying for various postdoc grants"); the second sentence suggests they are following a particular format that stands in for a generic CV ("They all have some section")

Comment: Good point, @BryanKrause. Then my point about funding agencies applies, and they should follow any regulations they can find to the letter.